# VF Page Error : "Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex"

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcedx

loading my VF page i am getting the below error:

Error : Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex

VF Page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Statement__c" extensions="Payments_Extension" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Quick Payment" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save Payment" action="{!savePayment}" disabled="{!success}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

                <apex:selectList label="Payment Method" value="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId}">
                    <apex:selectOption value="{!paymentRecordTypes}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="paymentMethodDetails"/>
                </apex:selectList>

                <apex:inputfield value="{!thisPayment.Amount__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!thisPayment.Billing_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!thisPayment.Billing_Street__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!thisPayment.Billing_City__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!thisPayment.Billing_State__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!thisPayment.Billing_Postal_Code__c}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:outputPanel id="paymentMethodDetails">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId!=null && 
                                                             recordTypeMap[thisPayment.recordTypeId] == 'Check'}">

                    <apex:inputfield value="{!thisPayment.Check_Account_Number__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!thisPayment.Check_Routing_Number__c}"/>

                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId!=null 
                                                             && recordTypeMap[thisPayment.recordTypeId] =='Credit Card'}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!thisPayment.Credit_Card_Number__c}"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputField value="Credit Card Expiration"/>
                        <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!thisPayment.Credit_Card_Expiration_month__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!thisPayment.Expiration_Year__c}"/>
                            <apex:selectList value="{!thisPayment.Expiration_Year__c}">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!expirationYears}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:outputPanel>

                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:inputSecret value="{!thisPayment.Credit_Card_Security_Code__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller class :

```
    public class Payments_Extension{

   //payment__c record variable to hold payment information
    public Payment__c thisPayment{get;set;}
    public Statement__c thisStatement{get;set;}
    public Map<Id,String> recordTypeMap{get;set;}
    public boolean success{get;set;}

    public Payments_Extension(ApexPages.StandardController Scon){
        if(scon.getRecord() instanceOf Statement__c){
            thisStatement = [Select id,name, Rental_Agreement__r.balance__c,Statement__c.Balance__c,Rental_Agreement__r.Renter__c from Statement__c where id=:scon.getId()];
        }
        success=false;
        recordTypeMap = new Map<Id,String>();
        //query for all the record Types in payments object
        //and store it in recordTypeMap
        for(RecordType rtype:[Select id,name from RecordType where sobjecttype='Payment__c']){
            recordTypeMap.put(rtype.id,rtype.Name);
            System.debug('recordTypeMap == '+recordTypeMap);
        }
        //instansiate the payment

        thisPayment = new Payment__c();
        if(scon.getRecord() instanceOf Statement__c){
            thisPayment.Statement__c = scon.getId();
            thisPayment.Amount__c = thisStatement.Balance__c;
        }
        //if it is a guest User, present type to credit card.
        if(getIsGuest()){
            for(id i:recordTypeMap.keySet()){
                if(recordTypeMap.get(i) == 'Credit Card'){
                    thisPayment.RecordTypeId = i;
                }
            }
        } 
        else if(scon.getRecord() instanceOf Statement__c){
            Contact renter = [Select id,firstName,lastName,mailingStreet, mailingCity,
                             mailingState,mailingpostalcode from Contact where id=:thisStatement.Rental_Agreement__r.renter__c];

            thisPayment.Billing_Name__c=renter.FirstName+' '+renter.LastName;
            thisPayment.Billing_Street__c=renter.MailingStreet;
            thisPayment.Billing_City__c=renter.MailingCity;
            thisPayment.Billing_State__c=renter.MailingState;
            thispayment.Billing_Postal_Code__c=renter.MailingPostalCode;
        }
    }

    //this Method will Process and save our Payment.
    //or report any errors in attempt
    public PageReference savePayment(){
        success=false;
        string paymentType = recordTypeMap.get(thispayment.RecordTypeId);
        //Validation 
        if(validateFields(paymentType)){
            //process credit Card payment
            if(paymentType =='Credit Card'){
                //create a request wrapper for authorize.net
                API_authorizeDotNet.authnetReq_Wrapper req = new API_authorizeDotNet.authnetReq_Wrapper();
                //set up the wrapper values
                req.amt=string.valueOf(thisPayment.Amount__c);
                req.firstname=(thisPayment.Billing_Name__c.contains(' '))?thisPayment.Billing_Name__c.substringBefore(''):thisPayment.Billing_Name__c;
                req.lastname =(thisPayment.Billing_Name__c.contains(' '))?thisPayment.Billing_Name__c.substringAfter(' '):thisPayment.Billing_Name__c;
                req.billcity = thisPayment.Billing_City__c;
                req.billState = thisPayment.Billing_State__c;
                req.billzip = thisPayment.Billing_Postal_Code__c;

                //set the credit card req in the Wrapper.
                req.ccnum = thisPayment.Credit_Card_Number__c;
                req.ccexp = monthmap.get(thisPayment.Credit_Card_Expiration_month__c)+thisPayment.Expiration_Year__c;
                req.ccsec = thisPayment.Credit_Card_Security_Code__c;

                //give this req a name
                req.ordername = 'Payment of '+[Select id,name,Statement__c.Balance__c from Statement__c where id=:thisPayment.Statement__c].name;
                //process our authorize.net
                API_authorizeDotNet.authNetResp_Wrapper res = API_authorizeDotNet.authdotnetcharge(req);
                thisPayment.Authorize_net_Transaction_Id__c = res.transactionId;
                thisPayment.Authorize_net_Authorization_code__c = res.authorizationCode;
                thisPayment.Authorize_net_Response__c=res.responseCode + '|'+res.responseReasontext;

                //if the transaction is failed.
                if(res.responseCode!='1' || res.responseReasontext!='This transaction has been approved.'){
                    thisPayment.Status__c ='Failed';
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Payment Failed'));
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'res.responseReasontext'));
                    return null;
                }
            }
            //successful transaction
            thisPayment.Status__c='Paid';
            thisPayment.Payment_Date__c=system.now();
            upsert thisPayment;
            success=true;
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Payment Successful'));

            try{
                //if there is an email provided by the renter on the Contact object.
                if(thisStatement!=null && thisStatement.Rental_Agreement__r.renter__r.email!=null){
                    //construct my message
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    msg.setToAddresses(new List<String> {thisStatement.Rental_Agreement__r.renter__r.email});
                    msg.setSubject('Payment Confirmation');
                    msg.setHtmlBody('Your Payment of '+thisPayment.Amount__c +'has been processed.<br/><br/> Thank You!!');
                    msg.setPlainTextBody('Your Payment of '+thisPayment.Amount__c +'has been processed.\n\n Thank You!!');
                    //send the email
                    Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{msg});
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
        else{
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR,'Please fill out all the details'));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean validateFields(String paymentType){
        boolean valid = true;

        //check the common Fields
        if(thisPayment.Statement__c==null)
            valid=false;
        if(thisPayment.Amount__c==null)
            valid=false;
        if(string.isBlank(thisPayment.Billing_Name__c))
            valid=false;
        if(string.isBlank(thisPayment.Billing_Street__c))
            valid=false;
        if(string.isBlank(thisPayment.Billing_City__c))
            valid=false;
        if(string.isBlank(thisPayment.Billing_State__c))
            valid=false;
         if(string.isBlank(thisPayment.Billing_Postal_Code__c))
            valid=false;
       //check the specific fields related to the Payment type
       //check fileds when the payment type is check.
        if(paymentType == 'Check'){
            if(string.isBlank(thisPayment.Check_Account_Number__c))
                valid=false;
             if(string.isBlank(thisPayment.Check_Routing_Number__c))
                valid=false;
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public boolean getIsGuest(){

        return[Select id,userType from Profile where id=:userInfo.getProfileId()].userType =='Guest';
    }

       public static Map<String,String> monthMap=new Map<String,String>{
         'January'=>'01',
         'February'=>'02',
         'March'=>'03',
         'April'=>'04',
         'May' =>'05',
         'June'=>'06',
         'July'=>'07',
         'August'=>'08',
         'September'=>'09',
         'October'=>'10',
         'November'=>'11',
         'December'=>'12'
    };

      public list<selectOption> getPaymentRecordTypes(){

            list<selectOption> temp= new list<selectOption>();
            temp.add(new selectOption('','Select Payment Method'));
            for(id i : recordTypeMap.keySet()){
                temp.add(new selectOption(i,recordTypeMap.get(i)));
            }
            return temp;

        }

    public list<selectOption> getExpirationYears(){

        List<selectOption> temp = new List<selectOption>();

        for(integer i=0;i<5;i++){
            String y = ''+System.today().addYears(i).year();
            temp.add(new selectOption(y,y));
        }
        return temp;

    }

}
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE; check out [ask] for getting the best response. In particular, you dumped too much code given the nature of the issue at hand

Answer (score 2):

Your VF markup is using the wrong component

```
<apex:selectList label="Payment Method" value="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId}">
   <apex:selectOption value="{!paymentRecordTypes}"/>
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="paymentMethodDetails"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

- [apex:selectoption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOption.htm?search_text=apex:selectOption) is for a single selectOption
- [apex:selectOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm?search_text=apex:selectOption) refers to a collection of objects of type `SelectOption`

So, you want:

```
 <apex:selectList label="Payment Method" value="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!paymentRecordTypes}"/>
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="paymentMethodDetails"/>
 </apex:selectList>
```